# How to better express equality checking when nulls are present?

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I have the following code:

```
if ((document.StreetNumber ?? "") == (streetNumber ?? ""))
{
    validDocuments.Add(document);
}
```

In this example either `document.StreetNumber` or the `streetNumber` string variable can be either null or empty.  And they are equal to each other even if one is empty and the other one is null.

Is there a better way to express the comparison?  This seems unnecessarily verbose and ugly.

Comment: Beyond wrapping it up the equality check in a method, I'm not sure there's a less verbose way to write it.

Comment: You Can use String.IsNullOrEmpty(streetNumber );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me , Wrapping the Logic in a function is the best way to do it.

```
bool AreStringsEqual(string s1, string s2)
{
    return (s1 ?? "") == (s2 ?? "");
}
```

and you can use it this way:

```
if (AreStringsEqual(document.StreetNumber, streetNumber ))
{
    validDocuments.Add(document);
}
```

Comment: You had it right the first time.  A check for equality is also needed.

Comment: @AngryHacker Updated glad that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question already contains the best answer.

One possible little helper could be a static utility method, but it's just lipstick on a pig:

```
static class StringHelper {
  static Boolean Eq(this String s1, String s2) {
    return String.Equals(s1 ?? "", s2 ?? "", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

The final call would be something like:

```
if (document.StreetNumber.Eq(streetNumber)) {}
```

A radically different approach would be to remove earlier the null string, by expressing the meaning through an object that encapsulate the logic you need to convey:

```
class Street { // Or address
  String Number { get; }
  pubilc Street(String number) {
    Number = number ?? "";
  }
}
```

And eventually by comparing the two Numbers, or even better the two `Street`/`Address` objects, once you implement the equality/comparison.

```
if(street1 == street2)
  ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately that object is out of my hands.  Otherwise, yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: This is one more reason to wrap the external object into your business logic entity and leave inside this business entity the logic you need!  Still, i think your answer is good enough in many occasions.